# Laws for Dasa and Dasis

Tags: ramayana, smriti

So from an answer previously, I heard how Rama Rajyam employed slavery ie Dasa and Dasi to be gifted to Brahmins. I have a few questions, however. Number one how does one become a Dasa or Dasi? What are the rules for the treatment of Dasa or Dasi in different areas ie a Brahmin place or a king's palace?